# Apache Solr - Alternate ways to boost results

Tags: php, apache, search, solr, lucene

I'm new to Solr and would feel like there are other ways of boosting results other than using "qf" and "pf" parameters.

Can someone just give me an alternate way to do this. I have three fields and would like to base my boost(s) on those three fields.

Lets say there is a field with boolean values ( either 1 or 0 ), I want to boost results that take value 1. Is there a way to do this? we'll have to write an "if" condition of some sort am I right? simply, is there a way to get it done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using edismax, or dismax query parsers , which is most probably the case- you can use bq (boost query), or bf (boost function)

So for your example, I would add a boost query like this

```
bq=Myfield:1^2.0
```

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#bq_.28Boost_Query.29

If you are using the standard query parser, you can use the `BoostQParserPlugin`, and type your query like this: `q={!boost b=xxx}query`

You can also use solr magic parameter `_val_` which affects boosting score, and doesn't affect the matching.